# get xml attribute value using perl

Tags: xml, regex, perl

I'm pretty new in Perl scripting. I need help to get the XML attribute value of total-alarms (in this case 11).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alarm-response-list xmlns="url.com" throttle="11" total-alarms="11">
  <alarm-responses>
    <alarm id="51ebf6fc-0571-1001-0162-008014000af00" />
    <alarm id="51ec0320-07af-1001-0162-008010400af00" />
    <alarm id="51ebf6f4-0564-1001-0162-008014000af00" />
    <alarm id="51ec1512-0bb2-1001-0162-008010400af00" />
    <alarm id="51ec157d-0bed-1001-0162-008010040af00" />
    <alarm id="51ebae1b-fa31-1000-0162-008010004af00" />
    <alarm id="51ec06d4-08bf-1001-0162-00801000a4f00" />
    <alarm id="51e8303f-740a-1000-0162-008014000af00" />
    <alarm id="51ebeabc-0352-1001-0162-008010400af00" />
    <alarm id="51ebf74d-0593-1001-0162-008010040af00" />
    <alarm id="51ebf78d-05b3-1001-0162-008010004af00" />
  </alarm-responses>
</alarm-response-list>
```

Unsuccessfully, I tried to use the following Perl code:

```
my $parser4 = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc4 = $parser4->parse_file($current_working_dir.'\POSTres.xml');
my $xc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new( $doc4->documentElement()  );
my $nod = $xc->findnodes('//alarm-response-list');
print "A: ".$nod->getAttributes("total-alarms")."\n";
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here a way using `XML::Twig` module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    twig_roots => {
        '/alarm-response-list' => sub { printf qq|%s\n|, $_->att('total-alarms') },
    },  
)->parsefile(shift);
```

Run it like:

```
perl script.pl xmlfile
```

That yields:

```
11
```

Comment: How can I save the value in variable outside of the anonymous subroutine? instead of just print it on screen.

Comment: declare a variable before the parse and assign to it in the handler. The magic of closures will make it work.

Answer (score 3):

Your XPath expression doesn't match, because you specified a namespace in the XML document:

```
<alarm-response-list xmlns="url.com" ...
```

If we register that namespace in the XPath context, then we can extract the data with XPath:

1. Register the namespace. E.g.

   ```
   $xc->registerNs('a' => "url.com");
   ```
2. Use that namespace in the XPath, e.g.

   ```
   my ($alarms) = $xc->findvalue('//a:alarm-response-list/@total-alarms');
   ```

This now extracts the value of the attribute, as expected.